# How do you automate "add a semicolon at line end and go to next line " in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

When using Visual Studio Code, we can use use the shortcut 'Shift+Enter' to start an new line below and go to the head of the new line.

However, when coding in languages like Rust, C/C++ or Javascript whose statements end with a semicolon, ';', one may want there is a shortcut to add a semicolon at the end of current line before starting an new line.

Was wondering what are the shortcut or how to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `;` and `Return` is just two keypresses, the same as a shortcut?

Comment: Likely, would be 'END' -> "Shift+," -> Return

Comment: Speaking of javascript, you could install prettier extension. Set `semi: true` and never bother about it ever again.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko that's true :)

Answer (score 0):

For no-language-specific, one can use 'macros', please reference https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros.

Here are my settings:
 1. the macro:

```
 "macros": {
        "addSemiAndGoNext": [
            "cursorEnd",
            {"command": "type", "args": {"text": ";"}},
            "editor.action.insertLineAfter"
        ]
    }
```

2. Shortkey used: `Alt+;`

Hope it can be useful. If there are other ways, welcome sharing~

Comment: You can simplify with typing `";\n"`